# include() messing up HTML structure

Tags: html, include, structure, head

I have a little problem. I have header.php and footer.php files which I include in every page. In the header.php I have the `<head>` tag with the scripts/styles and a div which is the top bar. In the footer.php I have closing tags.

```
 <?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <div class="content">
       <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>
 <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

The problem is when I structure a page like the code above, my code is messed up, here is a picture http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/9640/92571581.jpg 
As you can see, the whole head seaction goes inside body.
If I copy paste the code from header.php and footer.php without including, everything works as it should, picture here http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/2603/98557724.jpg

What is the problem ? Every tag is opened and closed in the right place.

Thank you

Comment: Did you make sure that you don't have a lot tabs/whitelines in the header.php and footer.php

Comment: Only indented code, no white spaces.

Comment: are you adding the `header.php` and `footer.php` in all pages.if so you need it only in `index.php` not in other files....

Comment: Sorry, but didn't work. The strange thing is that only some pages act like this, other work normally

Answer (score 0):

When you open a html page it loads automatically the default head. Your php code is running after that loading. Try not to use that include.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I solve this ? I don't want to copy/paste the hole header/footer code in every page.   L.E. So is there another way other than php include ?

Comment: You have 2 options. Copy and paste it in every file or create unique pages with dynamic content.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic content ? I only have few pages, and most of them get their content from a database

Comment: Use javascript to handle your links when you change the page , and Unload the div content and load the new content from a php file.